# Xamarin Forms Subclass with Modified Bindable Property Defaults

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to get a subclass of the Xamarin Forms "Label" class.  In my subclass, among a lot of other changes, I want to have a *different* default value for some bindable properties (such as FontSize and FontAttributes).  However, if I set these in the constructor, it seems that Style specifiers won't override these, presumably because the bindings are already noticing that they are using non-default values.  Is there a way to specify in a subclass that you want to use different default values in a bindable property?

```
class MyCustomLabel : Label {
  public MyCustomLabel() {
    FontSize=20;
  }
}

<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="Superbig" TargetType="MyCustomLabel">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="3" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

<MyCustomLabel Style="{StaticResource Superbig}" Text="Hi There!" />
```

Here, the Superbig style is not being applied because I am setting the new default value in the constructor.  Therefore, I was hoping either (a) there was some other way to set a new default value, or (b) there was some other way to set a style so it overrode any value that was already set.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible. Static properties, as the bindable is, cannot be overriden. And the styles 'runs' before the constructor. What if you set the new default value only if its the 'default default'? (Sorry my bad English)

Comment: Your English is fine.  Is there a way to know if the default has been changed?  A simple comparison wouldn't work because someone might change it back to the original.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way is by the OnPropertyChanged event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `BindableProperty` doesn't seem to support `OverrideMetadata` like `DependencyProperty` does. Here's two way to achieve this.

1) Set a default `Style` for your `MyCustomLabel` object (XAML)

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Default style-->
        <Style TargetType="local:MyCustomLabel">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        </Style>

        <!--Superbig style-->
        <Style x:Key="Superbig" TargetType="local:MyCustomLabel">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

2) Create a new `FontSize` `BindableProperty` (C#)

```
public class MyCustomLabel : Label
{
    public MyCustomLabel()
    {
        base.SetBinding(Label.FontSizeProperty, new Binding(nameof(FontSize))
        {
            Source = this,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        });
    }

    //Don't forget the "new" keyword
    public new double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    //Don't forget the "new" keyword
    public static readonly new BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FontSize), typeof(double), typeof(MyCustomLabel), 40.0);
}
```

Comment: One issue with #1 above is that I was putting this into a class library, and therefore the library doesn't have access to the application styles.  I got around this by creating a "fake" page where I added the resources.  Then, I created a "boot" function in the library which gets passed in the "app" object, and then copies the resources from the "fake" page into the app's resources.

Comment: @johnnyb - BTW, its not necessary to create a fake page, just to have somewhere to attach resources, that you then copy to app resources. Simply create a `ResourceDictionary` e.g. `MyResourceDictionary.xaml` containing `<ResourceDictionary ...`, and then copy all its key/value pairs.