# Xaml using hidden property

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, xamarin.forms, properties

I have made a custom control which has a property `X` - which hides the `VisualElement.X` property of parent.

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentView // is a distant child of VisualElement
{
    public new double X
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { Console.WriteLine("I was not called with: " + value); }
    }
}
```

I set the `X` of the custom control in xaml:

```
<controls:MyCustomControl X="10" />
```

But here the `Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.X` property setter is called instead of the `MyCustomControl.X` setter. Why? And how can I make it so my custom control property is used instead?

---

As a side note. When `x:Name="myCustomControl` and `myCustomControl.X = 10` in code behind - then the setter of `MyCustomControl` is called.

---

When declaring property that does not exist in parent:

```
public double AnotherX
{
    get { return 0; }
    set { Console.WriteLine("Was called with: " + value); }
}
```

the setter is called. (From xaml).

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/378331#Comment_378331

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are setting the BindableProperty 'X' of the VisualElement through the Xaml.
It should work if you create a BindableProperty 'X' in your custom control as well.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958569/1997232) demonstrates how to *hide* `BindableProperty`. It does so to override default value though.

Comment: But does xaml look for `BindableProperties` first? In this situation the `BindableProperty` seem to hide the property in my custom control. Can I somehow tell xaml to look for child property first. Is there a solution without declaring a `BindableProperty` in child?

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't be trying to override X you should be using a new name
2. you create a bindableproperty not just a property see below on how to make a bindable property

   ```
   private readonly BindableProperty CustomXProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomX), typeof(double), typeof(MyCustomControl), defaultValue: 0.0);

   public double CustomX
   {
       get
       {
           return (double)GetValue(CustomXProperty);
       }
       set
       {
           SetValue(CustomXProperty, value);
       }
   }
   ```

Please see here for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Comment: The setter is still not called. I have noticed that `propertyChanged` has been necessary to declare before. Also, are all the properties accessible in xaml `BindableProperty`s - not using the "normal" properties at all?

Comment: No, I can define a property in my custom control that does not exist parent - which become visible in xaml. And the setter of this property will be called.

Comment: But I assume then that `xaml` is looking for `BindableProperty`s first - and the normal `properties` afterwards.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking?